# python script to convert nucleotide sequence in table to fasta format

Tags: python, data-conversion, fasta

I have performed ancestral sequence reconstructions to determine the nucleotide sequence for each node of a given phylogenetic tree. The output file is a table with the most probable nucleotide at each position for each node (see below):

```
#output file:
node_name, position, nucleotide
node1, 1, A
node1, 2, T
node1, 3, G
....
node2, 1, A
node2, 2, T
node2, 3, G
...
```

I would like to convert this output file into a fasta file, like this:

```
>node1
ATG....
>node2
ATG....
.....
```

How can I do this task with a python function, with R, or with a shell script (with awk and sed commands)?

Best regards,

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
import csv

def csv_to_fasta(csv_file, fasta_file):

    seq = {}

    with open(csv_file) as fin:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fin, skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in reader:
            node_name = row['node_name']
            if node_name not in seq:
                seq[node_name] = ''
            seq[node_name] += row['nucleotide']

    with open(fasta_file, 'w') as fout:
        for node_name, nucleotides in seq.items():
            fout.write(f'>{node_name}\n{nucleotides}\n')
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you very much for your help, it works perfectly. I better understand the functionalities of csv module. Cheers. Gabriel